# Where are my .dylib files on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, installation

I'm walking through this tutorial on setting up OpenCV on a Mac OS X. I came to step(5), where I had to add the `.dylib` files. The author mentioned to look in `/usr/local/lib`, but couldn't find such files.

Where can I find them on the Mac machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're following [this](http://tilomitra.com/opencv-on-mac-osx/) then you're building the dylibs yourself, and they should be wherever the earlier `make install` step puts them. Copies of them should also be somewhere in the directory where you built OpenCV, so you could just link to them there.